# What is the problem with my shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to print the armstrong sum of a number, but I'm getting the following error :

> expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘armstrong.sh’ expr: syntax
> error: missing argument after ‘+’

Where is the problem?

```
echo "Enter number"
read n
declare l=0
declare num=$n
while [ $num -gt 0 ]  
do
l=`expr $l + 1`
num='expr $num / 10'
done
num=$n
declare sum=0
declare d=0
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
d=`expr $num % 10`
dum=`expr $d ** $l`
sum=`expr $sum + $dum`
num=`expr $num / 10`
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: This URL can check the syntax of your script: https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Enter number"
read n
declare l=0
declare num=$n
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
l=`expr $l + 1`
num=`expr $num / 10`
done
num=$n
declare sum=0
declare d=0
while [ $num -gt 0 ]
do
d=`expr $num % 10`
dum=`expr $d \* $l`
sum=`expr $sum + $dum`
num=`expr $num / 10`
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: You are making two mistakes i.e. inline 8 use `` instead of '' and in line 16 use \* instead of * as in expr we need to use * with a \